# An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.3) and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rvm, bundler

I am facing `pg` gem issue for my Rails project on `bundle install` and it is using using ruby-2.2.2 and rails (4.2.0) on Macbook. I am getting the following error:
`An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.3) and Bundler cannot continue`.
Can anyone assist how it can be fixed?

Comment: Please add error in question

Comment: I faced this issue on pg 0.18.2
solution for this is:

```gem install pg -v '0.18.2' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it on my Macbook by installing `libpqxx` using below command:

```
brew install libpqxx
```

On Ubuntu, you can run below command to fix this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```